# Attribute routes with the same name 'upload' must have the same template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have 2 controllers

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using shadow.Data;
using shadow.DTO;
using shadow.Models;
using shadow.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace shadow.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserTrustedPersonController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IUserService _userService;
        private IMailService _mailService;
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public static IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

        public UserTrustedPersonController(IUserService userService, IMailService mailService, IConfiguration configuration, ApplicationDbContext db, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _mailService = mailService;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _db = db;
            _environment = environment;
        }

        public class FileUploadAPI
        {
            public IFormFile files { get; set; }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("upload2")]
        [Obsolete]
        public async Task<string> Post(FileUploadAPI objFile)
        {
            try
            {
                if (objFile.files.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\Upload\\"))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\Upload\\");
                    }
                    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\Upload\\" + objFile.files.FileName))
                    {
                        objFile.files.CopyTo(fileStream);
                        fileStream.Flush();
                        return "\\Upload\\" + objFile.files.FileName;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Failed";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }

        // Upload file ảnh.
        [HttpPost("upload", Name = "upload")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (CheckIfExcelFile(file))
            {
                await WriteFile(file);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Invalid file extension" });
            }
            return Ok();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to check if file is excel file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool CheckIfExcelFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            var extension = "." + file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
            return (extension == ".png" || extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".bmp" || extension == ".gif" || extension == ".tif"); // Change the extension based on your need
        }

        //private async Task<bool> WriteFile(IFormFile file)
        private async Task<string> WriteFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            bool isSaveSuccess = false;
            string fileName;
            string filePath ="";
            try
            {
                var extension = "." + file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
                fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks + extension; //Create a new Name for the file due to security reasons.
                var pathBuilt = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Upload\\files");
                if (!Directory.Exists(pathBuilt))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathBuilt);
                }
                var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Upload\\files", fileName);
                filePath = path;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                isSaveSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //log error
            }
            //return isSaveSuccess;
            return filePath;
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using shadow.Data;
using shadow.Models;
using shadow.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace shadow.Controllers
{

    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ImageFileController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IUserService _userService;
        private IMailService _mailService;
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public ImageFileController(IUserService userService, IMailService mailService, IConfiguration configuration, ApplicationDbContext context /*, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager */)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _mailService = mailService;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _db = context;
            // _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ImageFile>> AddImage(ImageFile imageItem)
        {
            var item = new ImageFile
            {
                //Fullname = trustedPerson.Fullname,
               
            };
            _db.ImageFiles.Add(item);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync(); 
            return item;
        }

        // Upload file ảnh.
        [HttpPost("upload", Name = "upload")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (CheckIfExcelFile(file))
            {
                await WriteFile(file);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Invalid file extension" });
            }
            return Ok();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to check if file is excel file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool CheckIfExcelFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            var extension = "." + file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
            return (extension == ".png" || extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".bmp" || extension == ".gif" || extension == ".tif"); // Change the extension based on your need
        }

        //private async Task<bool> WriteFile(IFormFile file)
        private async Task<string> WriteFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            bool isSaveSuccess = false;
            string fileName;
            string filePath = "";
            try
            {
                var extension = "." + file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
                fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks + extension; //Create a new Name for the file due to security reasons.
                var pathBuilt = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Upload\\files");
                if (!Directory.Exists(pathBuilt))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathBuilt);
                }
                var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Upload\\files", fileName);
                filePath = path;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                isSaveSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //log error
            }
            //return isSaveSuccess;
            return filePath;
        }

    }
}
```

Error

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The following errors occurred with attribute routing information:

Error 1:
Attribute routes with the same name 'upload' must have the same template:
Action: 'shadow.Controllers.ImageFileController.UploadFile (shadow)' - Template: 'upload'
Action: 'shadow.Controllers.UserTrustedPersonController.UploadFile (shadow)' - Template: 'UserTrustedPerson/upload'
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ApplicationModelFactory.Flatten[TResult](ApplicationModel application, Func`5 flattener)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorBuilder.Build(ApplicationModel application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.GetChangeToken()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Subscribe>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Subscribe()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource..ctor(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actions, ActionEndpointFactory endpointFactory)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at shadow.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__5_0(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in D:\shadow_backend\Startup.cs:line 120
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at shadow.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in D:\shadow_backend\Startup.cs:line 118
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```cs
        // Upload file ảnh.
        [HttpPost("upload", Name = "upload")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        { }
```

to

```cs
        // Upload file ảnh.
        [HttpPost("upload", Name = "uploadx")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        { }
```

The purpose is choose a different `Name` attribute of `HttpPost`, this is a different template.

Comment: This seems a bit hacky, I had a think and posted a cleaner approach above.

Answer (score 8):

In your code example you declare your routes using:

`[HttpPost("upload", Name = "upload")]` (User Controller)
`[HttpPost("upload", Name = "upload")]` (Image Controller)

**You can solve the issue and prevent the clash by declaring your routes in a different way:**

✔ `[HttpPost, Route("[controller]/upload")]` (User Controller)
✔ `[HttpPost, Route("[controller]/upload")]` (Image Controller)

Useful reading:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-name

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-up-conventional-route